# Access token removed in Facebook Android SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am using Facebook Android SDK 4.0 (newly updated version). I logged in to my app after the initial setup. Then I exited from my app. If again start my app, user is not in the logged in state. When I use debugger, it shows "ACCESS TOKEN REMOVED". What is the procedure to check whether the user is in logged in state using Access Token?

I have tried new log in method (according to newer version 4.0) in which they mentioned about log in process. I have done it. But whenever I open up Access Token state is "ACCESS TOKEN REMOVED". I checked App id, Package name, Activity name in dash board settings. All are correct. Help me to find solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Maybe you found something on the internet, tried that and for some reason it was not working?

Comment: Actually I have tried new log in method (according to newer version 4.0) in which they mentioned about log in process. I have done it. But whenever I open up Access Token state is "ACCESS TOKEN REMOVED". I checked App id, Package name,Activity name in dash board settings. All are correct. Help me to find solution for this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help, I asked that just to make it clearer for others that you had actually tried something.

Comment: Hello @user3026694 : have you find any solutions for this. I am facing the same issue. Please put here your answer if you have find it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @user1297214 i didn't find any solution till now. I couldn't make `GraphRequest` call. If I make `GraphRequest` , there is no response in `onCompleted(Response response)` method. If you find any solution, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hai @user3026694 ,I got the solution. I've execute GraphRequest method inside the separate thread. It is wrong approach. All asynch taks shoud be run inside the main thread. Try this.

Comment: @Che Am having same issue. Can u post your detailed solution here please?

Comment: @Divya Motiwala Graph request should called through main thread not through separate thread. Moreover 
`if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
}`

Use this method also.

Comment: I am also facing same issue please any body can help on it

Answer (score 17):

you can get access_token by using 
loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
as following code

```
 LoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

          String accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

        }
```

Comment: Nice . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13):

By default the SDK will not log access tokens to logcat (this is to avoid leaking user tokens via the log).

You can, however, enable in debug mode a logging behavior to log the access token. Just add this when you're calling `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()`, but make sure to only do it when you're in debug mode:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. @Ming Li

And, ACESSTOKEN : 

`state : ACCESS TOKEN REMOVED 
permissions : basic_ifo,public_profile`

When i used to print the access token , it shows like this. I cant able to make any graph request,  even i couldn't get any error response in `onCompleted(GraphResponse response)` method. I think its because of "ACCESS TOKEN REMOVED" state. So please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your code on how you're making the GraphRequest?

Comment: Hi @Ming Li ,
This is my code.

`Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, appId+"/scores",new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

// i cant get any response here. even i cant able to debug.
                    
                }
        });

request.executeAsync();`

When i debug, debugger doesn't show any values for local varaibles but it shows the global instance variable's  value. Help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the token by using

```
 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken()
```

Using this you can get the token at any time, if you use the LoginResult, you get it only once at the time you log in, when you restart the app the onSuccess is not called.

If you need the profile after restarting, you use

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```

If this returns null you are not loged in

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I've execute `GraphRequest` method inside the separate thread. It is wrong approach. All asynch taks shoud be run inside the main thread.