# Access Token Removed when posting facebook sdk 4.0 in Android

Tags: facebook, android-studio, access-token

By following the facebook sample for login and posting, after I do login and I get name and photo of my profile , when I try to post on wall in the following part..

```
if (accessToken != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) 
{ handlePendingAction();

        } else
        {
                          LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));
            return;
        }
    }
```

I get ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions: [user_friends,public_profile,basic info]
Why the permissions are removed if I successfully login. How can we fix it?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue with the latest SDK (v4.0.1) and sample HelloFacebookSample project. Can you try on a different device/emulator and see if you get the same issue? I would also uninstall the app from your [facebook app settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and try to oauth again.

Comment: Why and when we will get a message such that     {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_friends, basic_info]}  , shall I update the sdk? What kind of facebook app settings to change? I checked key hash, package name, single sign on. The only setting which now I am noticing is that publish_actions is an extra item that I shall put it in review

Comment: Are you trying this as a non-app admin/developer/tester? if so, then this won't work since extended permissions requires review. BUT this should still work for you if you are an admin/developer of the app.

Comment: So I logged in as the administrator and it seems that is working :) So when the app its ready for publish shall I ask for the extra permissions?

Comment: Yes, more about App Review [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review). Glad it worked for you. I will add my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some general tips to help you debug this:

- try to update to the latest SDK
- try on different devices/emulators
- try uninstalling the app and re-authorize from [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Now for permission specific issues, make sure to **always** test first with a user who's an Admin/Developer/Tester of an app, since your test will fail with normal user if you app is:

- not public (still in development mode)
- public BUT the permission you are testing against is not yet [approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) by Facebook

Comment: Also, "By default the SDK will not log access tokens...", check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/29544390/3921541

Comment: I still get "A page access token is required to request this resource" when I try to use "Page_ID/featured_videos_collection" after I granted manage_pages permission, I use my app admin account and testing on my fan page, knowing that the permission is not yet approved by Facebook, any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to override in your Activity the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```