# How to get the featured video of a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

To fetch a Facebook page videos I use the code below:

```
new GraphRequest(mAccessToken, "Page_ID/videos", params, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback(){}
```

What I want is to fetch the 'Featured video' of a Facebook page, but according to Facebook documentation in the link below, '**featured_video**' parameter is visible only to the page admin, **What is the logic behind setting this parameter to be only read by the page admin?**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

**Where can I report / ask Facebook to get this parameter result allowed to be read by others than the page admin?**

Comment: The question is not solved yet, any suggestions or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Graph API `/{page-id}/featured_videos_collection` gives Featured Videos Collection for a Facebook Page. You need to use page-access token with page-id.

See for [more info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/featured_videos_collection/). I have not tested that API. Check if it is working.

You need to use {page-id}/featured_videos_collection edge to get featured video with normal user with page-access-token. While authenticating user, you need to get `user_pages` permission. Admin can get featured_video in directly without giving user_pages permission in {page-d} edge only. May be because of that Facebook have kept different edge for getting featured video of a page and  'featured_video' parameter is visible only to the page admin

Comment: Thanks :) But still it requires page-access token to get the page featured video, which will not be available for the users of my application. And I don't understand why Facebook restricted to know the page featured video to page admins using page access token.

Comment: You can get page-access token by authenticating with `user_pages` scope to user with your application. Facebook have put restrictions to get page details and giving access only to page admins for featured videos of page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about user_pages permission, and whether granting this permission will allow the users to fetch the featured video of a page that they are not their admins.

Comment: While authenticating user, you need to get `user_pages` permission. So user will be able to get featured videos of any page (same like they are viewing in Facebook). But you need to use `{page-id}/featured_videos_collection` edge to get featured video. Admin can get featured_video in directly without giving user_pages permission in `{page-d}` edge only. May be because of that Facebook have kept different edge for getting featured video of a page.

Comment: I checked it out and there is no user_pages permission ... it shows me (invalid scope: user_pages) ... I also searched developers.facebook.com and couldn't find it.

Comment: I granted manage_pages permission via my app (The permission is not yet approved by FB), and when I tried to fetch the featured video (even for my own Facebook Fan page), it shows me error number #210 (A page access token is required to request this resource) ... I followed the advice / accepted answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/29652027/749796 And yet the error still happens, I tested on 2 devices and using my own FB personal account that manages / admins my app on Facebook and manages the fan page. Any advice?

Comment: OK, it turns out that I need to get a page access token first and using it to call the page_id/featured_videos_collection ... Still when I used Graph API Explorer on pages I don't admin, it returns me the error:     "message": "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page.",