# How to get Facebook information in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get information from my facebook in android , 
my code :

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+loginResult.getAccessToken(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    // Get facebook data from login
                    try {
                        object.get("gender");
                        object.get("email");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 //   Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }
```

But the program does not get into `public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) { 
the result of this function is :

```
{Request:  accessToken: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_photos, public_profile]}, graphPath: me, graphObject: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{}]}
```

Is there any solution? or this case related to facebook privacy settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
loginResult.getAccessToken()
```

with

```
loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken() .
```

Facebook doesn't allow devs to Log "session.getAccessToken" directly, because it may cause leaks.Can also check this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29544390/2754871

Answer (score 1):

Try the building your login flow manually. This way you don't get stuck on the `sdk`.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow
```